# C言語での絶対値の定義

Tags: c

C言語で絶対値を定義しようと思い、以下のように定義しました。

何回コンパイルしてもエラーばかり出てくるので、どこかが間違ってるのだとは思いますが、どこが間違っているのかがわかりませんでした。下記のプログラムの前半「int myabs1(int x)」のところは正しいと思うのですが、じゃあ「int main(void)」のところが間違ってるのでしょうか。（ちなみに私は、最初「int a;  a=myabs1();」のところを書いていなかったので、そこを付け足したのですが、それでもエラーが出てしまいました。なので、a=myabs1(x)としたのですが、それでもだめでした。）

```
int myabs1(int x)
{
    int abs;
    if(x>=0){
        abs=x;
    }else{
        abs=-x;
    }
    return abs;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a;
　　a=myabs1();
    printf("xの値は: \n");
    printf("abs=%d",a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: エラーには必ず何かしらの意味があるので、「エラーが出た」で怯まず内容に注目する癖をつけることをおすすめします。 / そして質問する際もエラーの内容を含めるようにしてください。

Comment: `a=myabs1(x)`のxは何でしょうか？mainでは定義されていないようです。

Answer (score 3):

[c](/questions/tagged/c) では、自作関数 `myabs1(int)` を作っても正しく呼ばないと実行されません。あなたの作った `myabs1` は `int` の引数を１つ取る仕様になっているので

```
int a = -3;
int b = myabs1(a);
printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
```

のように呼ぶ必要があります。 `int myabs1(int x) { ... }` の `x` は [c](/questions/tagged/c) の専門用語で仮引数と呼ばれる代物で、その名前の変数は `myabs1` の中にしかありません (`main` 中に `x` という変数は存在せず、この `x` に相当する値を `main` から `myabs1` に与える必要があります)

# `myabs1(-2147483648)` は誤動作します・・・

Answer (score 1):

> int myabs1(int x)
>
> a=myabs1();

myabs1関数はint型の引数を一つ取りますが、それを使用しているところでは、引数がありません。

---

> a=myabs1(x)としたのですが、それでもだめでした。

エラーメッセージをきちんと読もう。
英語だからわからんってことなら、翻訳サイトもあります